# How to progate an event to a children

Tags: events, javafx-2, draw

I have code like this:

```
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        //if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
        if ( ( event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED )&&
             (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) ) {
                x1 = x2 = event.getX();
                y1 = y2 = event.getY();
                line = new BoundLine(pane, event, x1, y1,  x2, y2);
                pane.getChildren().add(line);                    
                //line.getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent(event, null);
        }
   }
```

Is it possibile to propagate immediately the "MouseEvent event" to the `javafx.scene.shape.Line` (line in the code) object ? I have tried `line.getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent(event, null);` but I've got this message error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   testjavafxapplication.LinesEditCtx02$MouseHandler.handle(LinesEditCtx02.java:243)
>     at
>   testjavafxapplication.LinesEditCtx02$MouseHandler.handle(LinesEditCtx02.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: My goal is to pass mouse event from parent (pane) to children (line) immediately after children is created.

Example:

1) left mouse click anywhere on the chart
2) while keep pressed, from pane is create first point of a line
3) still pressed and drag a line is then created: this means that mouse event must be transferred from pane to line

Answer (score -1):

The EventDispatchChain (second argument) that is being sent to #dispatchEvent cannot be null.  Unfortunately there are no public implementations, or they are in com.sun packages so you would need to implement your own EventDispatchChain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you help me with an example, in order to propagate mouservent to line ?

Comment: I am not sure of the license restrictions on code in the com.sub.* or I would copy/paste the source of EventDispatchChainImpl.  I assume BoundLine has a mouse listener set on one of it's properties, couldn't you just call this directly with the mouse event instead of going through the dispatch mechanism?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried the method you suggested, but it does not work. Are there  other solutions?

Comment: getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent is the only way to propagate an event?